# primary expression before ")" token when copying parameters to an array of structure elements

Tags: c++

TimestampedConatiner.hpp:

```
#ifndef TIMESTAMPEDCONTAINER_HPP_
#define TIMESTAMPEDCONTAINER_HPP_

using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include <ctime>

template <class k, class d>
class timestampedContainer
{
private:
    struct elements
    {
        k keyType;
        d dataType;
        string timeStamp;
    };
    int position;
    int size;
    elements * containerPtr;

public:
    timestampedContainer(int);
    void insertElement(k,d);
    void getElement(int, k, d, string);
    void deleteContainer();
    ~timestampedContainer();
};

template<class k, class d>
timestampedContainer<k, d>::timestampedContainer(int size)
{
    position = 0;
    containerPtr = new elements[size];
}

template<class k, class d>
void timestampedContainer<k, d>::insertElement(k, d)
{
    if(position <= size)
    {
        containerPtr[position] = elements(k, d);
        position++;
    }

}
#endif
```

The error pops up in the insert element function when i try to copy the parameters into the array of element structures. Is there something wrong in the way I called it? What exactly does this error mean?

Comment: Your struct `elements` does not provide a constructor matching `elements(k, d)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the expression `elements(k, d)`.

1. `k` and `d` are types. Hence, `elements(k, d)` does not make sense at all.
2. `elements` does not have an explicitly defined constructor. Hence, you cannot construct an object of that type using a constructor-like call.

You may want to use something like:

```
template<class kType, class dType>
void timestampedContainer<kType, dType>::insertElement(kType k, dType d)
{
    if(position <= size)
    {
        containerPtr[position] = {k, d, ""};
        position++;
    }
}
```